# Randomly positioned words (links) over ever changing background

Tags: jquery, css, background, lightbox, sprite

After learning the basics of CSS and jQuery, I'd like to set up a simple site for an artistic purpose, layered like this:

1. A background image that resizes with the browser window; either picking a random image every day or as slideshow > probably best with superbgimage/supersized/similar solution?
2. Up to 11 randomly positioned divs, each containing a word (link), blurred, that come in focus on hover > blur/focus effect probably best done with CSS sprites and .png files?
3. Clicking a link overlays everything with a centered div in which texts and images appear, the content in that div should be scrollable if more content exists than the viewport can show > is this one of these "lightbox" or "modal window" things?

Please see this approximate schematic here:

[image]

I have particularly no idea how to achieve 2., **randomly** positioning words over a background. And regarding 3. I've only found examples for image galleries and the like, but not inline(?) html content that can be styled as any other content. But maybe the whole principle can not be achieved? I'm rather happy to learn, even at my age, so if you could point me in the right direction...

Comment: If it helps: that can all definitely be done.

Comment: 2. see also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224571/positioning-multiple-random-sized-absolutely-positioned-elements-so-they-dont

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286855/generate-random-element-position-and-prevent-overlapping-in-javascript

Comment: Hej thirtydot, can be done sound good. It's not a word cloud thing as seemed to be popular some years ago, but I'll look up those links. Thanks.

Comment: For number two, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302824/overlapping-elements-html-css-and-jquery/6302883#6302883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ok go for that
2. just generate a random number (in limits) with JS (Math.random()) and use this with $(element).css() - be sure to use the right CSS positioning
3. You are probably looking for sth like: http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Hej m90, as for 2. what you suggest there, I will try; as for 3. that does seem to be a good idea for non-image gallery uses as needed in my case, thanks for those hints.

Comment: Thanks for the pixastic link; what a simple good idea. But unfortunately this would exclude IE users, who are still the majority?

Comment: I think this only accounts for some of the advanced features. According to: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/ this will work in IE5.5+

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing this out, everything's blurred behind my bespectacled eyes. I tried it out and it looks rather well. If now some bright head would adapt such functionality for CSS styleable regular text...

Comment: You could use this along with dyamic font replacement (PHP in this case probably): http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dynatext/ which would let you use "standard" HTML text while still being able to blur the result

Comment: Found that David DeSandro's Isotope with transparent elements does the trick I was after fairly well. Idea was to visually match out-of-focus text to the depth of field of full screen background.