# jquery banner with random quotes in random positions

Tags: jquery, banner

I'm looking for a jquery script that will load various quotes randomly and into **random positions** over an image (banner). I know this is a vague question but I don't know how it can be achieved and I'm looking for something to begin with.

Comment: Where are the quotes coming from?

Comment: Maybe these links help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224571/positioning-multiple-random-sized-absolutely-positioned-elements-so-they-dont and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286855/generate-random-element-position-and-prevent-overlapping-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302824/overlapping-elements-html-css-and-jquery/6302883

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a daft idea, but have you considered using a tag cloud?  There are several ready-made plugins available (e.g. [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-cloud-plugin), [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TagCloud), [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCloud) and many [others](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tagcloud/)). It's not what a cloud is meant for, but if you used your quotes as tags and gave them all the same weighting it might give you the visual layout you are looking for and save some work (obviously switch any animations off). The div could then be styled to position over your image.

Just an idea.

Comment: Nice idea, never worked with a tag cloud before but I'll give it a try.