# jQuery Avoid Overlapping Containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, animation

I recently tried to work on a jQuery-Plugin which is used to spread an amount of containers randomly in a container to afterwards be able to animate them in a special way. You can see my attempts here: http://www.manuelmaurer.at/randposplugin.php

The Problem is, that some of them are overlapping and I can't figure out why. At first I thought that the reason for this might be that $.each() is not waiting for one loop to finish before starting the next one but I also tried to solve that using recursive functions - didn't help. I hope someone could give me a little push to figure out where the problem actually is, thanks in advance! You can see the code either on the page itself or just have a look at the following important parts.

---

This code is used to loop over all the elements. This is not further important, but the function "NoCollision" is trying to figure out, if an element exists in that area. If yes, it returns false, if the space can be used, it returns true. If the space can not be used, some random other coordinates are chosen and it will be tried again.

```
var Counter2 = 0;
    $(FlowContainer).children(':not(:last)').each(function(elem) {
        Counter2++;
        ElemNow = $(FlowContainer).children().eq(Counter2);
        ElemWidth = $(ElemNow).data("animwidth")
        ElemHeight = $(ElemNow).data("animheight")
        var Tries = 0;
        var TryNowX = ElemPrevLeft;
        var TryNowY = ElemPrevTop;
        while (!NoCollision(TryNowX, TryNowY, ElemWidth, ElemHeight, PositionsArray, Settings.MinSpreadX, Settings.MinSpreadY) && Tries <= Settings.MaxTries) {
            if (TryNowY < 15) {
                TryNowY += randomIntFromInterval(0, 10);
            } else if (TryNowY > (FlowContainer.height() - ElemHeight - 15)) {
                TryNowY += randomIntFromInterval(-10, 0);
            } else {
                TryNowY += randomIntFromInterval(-10, 10);
            }
            if (TryNowX < 15) {
                TryNowX += randomIntFromInterval(0, 10);
            } else if (TryNowX > (FlowContainer.width() - ElemWidth - 15)) {
                TryNowX += randomIntFromInterval(-10, 0);
            } else {
                TryNowX += randomIntFromInterval(-10, 10);
            }
            Tries++;
        }
        if (Tries == Settings.MaxTries) {
            console.log("Warning: Couldn't fit all elements - hiding some.")
            $(ElemNow).remove();
        } else {
            $(ElemNow).css({ top: TryNowY, left: TryNowX });
            ElemPrevLeft = TryNowX;
            ElemPrevTop = TryNowY;
            PositionArray = [TryNowY, TryNowX, ElemHeight, ElemWidth];
            PositionsArray[Counter2] = PositionArray;
        }
    })
```

The actual check, if the space can be used, takes part in the NoCollision-Function, which you can see in the following code.

```
function NoCollision(X, Y, W, H, PositionsArray, SpreadX, SpreadY) {
    var NoErrors = true;
    //Jedes Element im PositionsArray durchgehen und Prüfen
    $.each(PositionsArray, function(PositionArray) {
        var ArrY = PositionsArray[PositionArray][0];
        var ArrX = PositionsArray[PositionArray][1];
        var ArrW = PositionsArray[PositionArray][3];
        var ArrH = PositionsArray[PositionArray][2];
        if ((X < (ArrX - W - SpreadX) || X > (ArrX + ArrW + SpreadX)) && (Y < (ArrY - H - SpreadY) || Y > (ArrY + ArrH + SpreadY))) {
            //SHOULD BE OKAY HERE
        } else {
            NoErrors = false;
        }
    })
    return NoErrors;
}
```

The array which I am using to save the coordinates of all the already positioned divs looks like this.

```
PositionsArray[
    [Elem1PositionY, Elem1PositionX, Elem1Height, Elem1Width]
    [Elem2PositionY, Elem2PositionX, Elem2Height, Elem2Width]
]
```

---

My thought was to do it like this. Is there something wrong with the way I'd do it or is there a mistake in my implementation?

[image]

I am absolutely thankful for every bit of help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strongly suggest you get out of the habit of using global variables for everything you do in javascript and get in the habit of setting local ones using `var`, `let`, `const` etc. Will encounter numerous unpredictable and hard to debug issues using this poor practice

Comment: @charlietfl Hello, thanks for your feedback! I'm pretty new to this and try my best to learn it. Would you be so kind as to tell me which variables exactly you are talking about? -> There is not a single global one except the "FlowContainer"-Variable which achtually needs to be global. Or do I need to put "var ..." in front of every single variable declataration? Thanks for your help!

Comment: every variable declaration in code above is global because you don't use `var` or `let`

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, thank you - I didn't know that even if I use the variable in a function I have to use "var" to NOT declare it as global. I'll keep that in mind for the future and will change it as soon as possible, thank you very much!

Comment: yes...exactly....and can lead to lots of hard to find problems and possible collisions. If there is one important beginner habit to learn it is to always declare variables locally

Comment: @charlietfl - I already changed the code, all variables I used are now local ones :) That didn't solve the problem but at least I learned something useful for the future, thank you!

Comment: Please create a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in JsFiddle or similar. Javascript executes in a single thread so `$.each()` will wait for the current code to finish before starting the next, so that won't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue - my calculation of the overlapping was a bit wrong, just had to change the && (and) to || (or) - works like charm now.

Found a better solution using a plugin which was referenced on another  [stackoverflow-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286855/generate-random-element-position-and-prevent-overlapping-in-javascript/43345249#43345249) - works way better now.